# SignalR resolve client that called hub method

Tags: c#, signalr

I have signalR Hub:

```
    public class ServerHub : Hub
    {
        public void AnnounceIncomingCall(string name, string message)
        {
            return;
        }

        public bool ExecuteCall(Guid callId, int from, int to)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to resolve `Client` / `Connection` that called remotely method `ExecuteCall`? I would like to do this inside this method to answer exaclty to `Client` that have broadcasted the call.

I'm looking for something like `Clients.Current`?

Comment: is a javascript client or other client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Clients.Caller` property to get hold of the calling client. For more information, see [IHubCallerConnectionContext.Caller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.ihubcallerconnectioncontext.caller(v=vs.118).aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look on `Context.ConnectionId` and this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server